# Python: timeformat with timezone from helm

Tags: python, datetime, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to parse a timestamp that was generated from helm `helm list` command.
Now the timestamp format is something like this:
`2021-08-24 13:19:18.683572 +0800 +0800`
How can I parse it using python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you like to parse it? please explain in greater detail what troubles you have encountered

Comment: with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)? e.g. `datetime.strptime("2021-08-24 13:19:18.683572 +0800", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I want to build a datetime object from it, I tried to do:
`datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")`
But it sometime still fails, for example it failed to parse:
`ValueError: time data '2021-08-25 11:27:26.553493879 +0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'   `
The question is, is that format is a known format that I can use without strptime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When with string trimming:

```
    def _convert_time_to_iso_format(date_helm_format: str) -> datetime:
        """The helm time output format: 2021-08-24 13:19:18.683572 +0300 +0300
        Need to convert to iso format: 2021-08-24 13:19:18.683

        Args:
            date_helm_format (str): 2021-08-24 13:19:18.683572 +0300 +0300
        """
        (date, hour, tz, _) = date_helm_format.split(" ")
        hour = hour[0:-3] # remove nano-seconds, Python don't know how to handle it
        updated_date = date + " " + hour + " " + tz
        updated_date = datetime.strptime(updated_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")
        updated_date = updated_date - updated_date.utcoffset()
        return updated_date
```